# DropDownList with LinqDataSource and an empty option

Tags: asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu

Is there some elegant way to add an empty option to a DropDownList bound with a LinqDataSource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to add a value at the top of the list. It can be an empty string, or some text.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="categories" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="categoriesDataSource" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID" EnableViewState="False">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">
       -- Choose a Category --
    </asp:ListItem>           
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Be sure to set the DropDownList's AppendDataBoundItems=True.

Comment: Why don't you add that suggestion to your sample code for clarity?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Keltex. I thought my original version emphasized the point that the attribute had to be changed, but obviously it didn't.

Comment: As it turns out, just setting AppendDataBoundItems to true adds an empty option to the beginning. Like if it was there by default or what. If I add an asp:ListItem, I'll get 2 empty options. Anyway, your solution is cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQualQuestion" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsQualQuestion" DataTextField="ShortQuestionText" DataValueField="QualificationQuestionKey" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQualQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="ddlQualQuestion_DataBound" />;
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ddlQualQuestion_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  
  ddlQualQuestion.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the solution DOK provided:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="categories" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="categoriesDataSource" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID" EnableViewState="False">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">
       -- Choose a Category --
    </asp:ListItem>           
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Addtionally, if you don't want to force the user to make a selection you can add a method to the LinqDataSource of your GridView:

```
OnSelecting="myGridview_Selecting"
```

Add code behind like this:

```
protected void myGridview_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    if (categories.SelectedValue == "-1")
    {
        e.WhereParameters.Remove("CategoryID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd provide an extension method on `IEnumerable<string>` that prepended an item to the beginning of the list:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> Prepend(this IEnumerable<string> data, string item)
    {
        return new string[] { item == null ? string.Empty : item }.Union(data);
    }
```

Its sort of linq-y, as it uses the linq extension method Union.  Its a little cleaner than doing this:

```
var result = new string[]{string.Empty}.Union(from x in data select x.ToString());
```